# How to make child prevent ScrollView from scrolling

Tags: react-native

Context:

- I have a graph, where I allow a user to "scrub" their finger over the graph, and see a tooltip
- This graph is nested inside a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView> 
  <Graph>
</ScrollView>
```

Problem:

- I want to "disable" the scroll view when the touch is happening over that graph
- I'm not sure how to do that.

```
function Graph() { 
  return (
    <View onTouchStart={e => /* prevent ScrollView from scrolling */} />
  )
}
```

I know about `scrollEnabled` on `ScrollView`, but it won't be easy for me to thread that prop. Is there a way I can just "stop propagation" for that touch event, inside `Graph`?

`onTouchStart={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` does not do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution is the following:

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";

export const ScrollEnabledContext = createContext(null);

export default function StoppableScrollView(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const setIsEnabled = (bool) => {
    ref.current && ref.current.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: bool });
  };
  return (
    <ScrollEnabledContext.Provider value={setIsEnabled}>
      <ScrollView ref={ref} {...props} />
    </ScrollEnabledContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

By using `setNativeProps`, I prevent a render. I can reference ScrollEnabledContext in the child component to prevent scrolls. A bit brittle, but gets the job done. Would be fantastic if I didn't have to do this, and could use something like `stopPropagation`